# Product Pop-up using React and Django

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-hooks

I am working through a tutorial on React and creating an ecommerce store with a Django backend.

I am new to React.

I have been able to get the React "FrontEnd" home page to display the products from the Django "products.py" which is a simple JSON file stored in the Django file system using the React Axios library.

There is a product pop-up which displays the product information when the use clicks on the view button.

I can't work out how to direct the pop-up to the "products.py" file.

It is still drawing its information from the products.js in the React "FrontEnd" file system.

The code is below.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

The code for the product page is below.

**Bestsellershop.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { handleOutofStock } from '../../../helper/shopHelper';
import { RatingShop } from '../../../helper/helper';
import Quickview from '../../layouts/Quickview';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap'; 
import axios from 'axios'
class Bestsellershop extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error:null,
            modalshow: false,
            lastActiveBox: -1,
            data:[]
        }
        this.modalShow = this.modalShow.bind(this);
        this.modalClose = this.modalClose.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        var str = "GeeksforGeeks";
        this.setState({loading:true});
        axios
          .get('/api/products/')
          .then(res=>{
              console.log(res.data);
              this.setState({data:res.data, loading:false});
          })
          .catch(err =>{
              console.log(str)
              this.setState({error:err, loading:false});
      });
  }
  
    // Modal
    modalShow(index) {
        this.setState({ modalshow: true, lastActiveBox: index });
    }
    modalClose() {
        this.setState({ modalshow: false });
    }

    render() {
        const{data,error,loading}=this.state;
        return (
            <div className="section section-padding">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="section-title centered">
                        <span className="subtitle">SuperPharmacy Compounding</span>
                        <h3 className="title mb-0">Our Products</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        {error && (
                            <
                            error
                            header="There was some error"
                            content={JSON.stringify(error)}
                            />
                        )}
                        {/* Data */}
                        {data.map((item, i) => (
                            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6" key={i}>
                                <div className="sigma_product style-6">
                                    <div className="sigma_product-thumb">
                                        <Link to={"/product-single/" + item.id}>
                                            <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/" + item.image[0]} alt={item.title} />
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="sigma_product-body">
                                        <h5 className="sigma_product-title"> <Link to={"/product-single/" + item.id}>{item.title}</Link>
                                        </h5>
                                        <div className="sigma_rating">
                                            {RatingShop(item.rating)}
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="sigma_product-price">
                                            <span>${new Intl.NumberFormat().format((item.price * (100 - item.discount) / 100).toFixed(2))}</span>
                                            {item.discount > 0 || item.discount !== '' ?
                                                <span>${new Intl.NumberFormat().format((item.price).toFixed(2))}</span>
                                                : ''}
                                        </div>
                                        {/* Cart */}
                                        {item.stock === true ?
                                            <Link to="#" className="sigma_btn btn-sm">Add to Cart</Link>
                                            :
                                            <Link to="#" className="sigma_btn btn-sm" onClick={handleOutofStock}> Add to Cart</Link>
                                        }
                                        {/* Quick view */}
                                        <Link to="#" className="sigma_btn btn-sm light" onClick={(e) => this.modalShow(item.id)}> Quick View </Link>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                        {/* Data */}
                        {/* Modal (Quick View) */}
                        <Modal size="lg" show={this.state.modalshow} className="sigma_quick-view-modal" onHide={this.modalClose} aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" centered>
                            <Modal.Body className="sigma_modal-sec">
                                <div className="sigma_close" onClick={this.modalClose}>
                                    <span />
                                    <span />
                                </div>
                                <Quickview productId={this.state.lastActiveBox} />
                            </Modal.Body>
                        </Modal>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Bestsellershop;
```

The code for the modal pop-up is below.

**Quickview.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getProduct, handleOutofStock } from '../../helper/shopHelper';
import { RatingShop, socialShare, getTags } from '../../helper/helper';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Quickview extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            qty: 1
        }
        this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
        this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);
        this.openSocialPopup = this.openSocialPopup.bind(this);
    }
    increment() {
        this.setState({
            qty: this.state.qty + 1
        });
    }
    decrement() {
        this.setState({
            qty: this.state.qty > 1 ? this.state.qty - 1 : 1
        });
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ qty: event.target.value });
    }
    // Open window
    openSocialPopup(social) {
        window.open(social.link, "MsgWindow", "width=600,height=600")
        // alert(social.title)
    }
    render() {
        const productId = this.props.productId;
        const modalContent = getProduct(productId);
        return (
            <div className="row sigma_product-single">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="sigma_product-single-thumb">
                        <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/" + modalContent.image[0]} alt={modalContent.title} className="w-100" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="sigma_product-single-content">
                        <h3>{modalContent.title}</h3>
                        <div className="sigma_product-price">
                            <span>${new Intl.NumberFormat().format((modalContent.price * (100 - modalContent.discount) / 100).toFixed(2))}</span>
                            {modalContent.discount > 0 || modalContent.discount !== '' ?
                                <span>${new Intl.NumberFormat().format((modalContent.price).toFixed(2))}</span>
                                : ''}
                        </div>
                        <div className="sigma_rating-wrapper">
                            <div className="sigma_rating">
                                {RatingShop(modalContent.rating)}
                            </div>
                            <span>{modalContent.reviews.length} Reviews</span>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <p className="sigma_product-excerpt">
                            {modalContent.shorttext}
                        </p>
                        <div className="sigma_product-meta">
                            <p><strong>Product SKU: <span>#{modalContent.sku}</span></strong></p>
                            <p><strong>Availablity:
                                {modalContent.stock === true ?
                                    <span>In Stock</span>
                                    :
                                    <span>Out of Stock</span>
                                }
                            </strong></p>
                            <p><strong>Tags: </strong>
                                {getTags(modalContent.tags).map((tag, i) => (
                                    <Link to={"/shop/tag/" + tag.id} key={i}>{tag.title} ,</Link>
                                ))}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <form className="sigma_product-atc-form">
                            <div className="sigma_product-buttons d-block">
                                {/* Cart */}
                                {modalContent.stock === true ?
                                    <button type="button" className="ml-0 btn-block sigma_btn">Add To
                                        Cart <i className="far fa-shopping-basket" /></button>
                                    :
                                    <button type="button" onClick={handleOutofStock} disabled className="ml-0 btn-block sigma_btn">Add To Cart <i className="far fa-shopping-basket" /></button>
                                }
                                {/* Wishlist */}
                                <Link to="#" className="ml-0 btn-block sigma_btn light">Add To Wishlist <i className="far fa-heart" /> </Link>
                                <Link to="#" className="ml-0 btn-block sigma_btn light">Compare <i className="far fa-compress" />
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        {/* Post Meta Start */}
                        <div className="sigma_post-single-meta">
                            <div className="sigma_post-single-meta-item sigma_post-share">
                                <h5>Share</h5>
                                <ul className="sigma_sm">
                                    {/* Data */}
                                    {socialShare(modalContent.title).map((social, i) => (
                                        <li key={i}>
                                            <Link to="#" onClick={(e) => this.openSocialPopup(social, i)}>
                                                <i className={social.iconClass} />
                                            </Link>
                                        </li>
                                    ))}
                                    {/* Data */}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {/* Post Meta End */}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Quickview;
```

Update -  I have located a helper function file called 'ShopHelper.js'.  It contains a function getProduct(id).  That function refers to an internal json 'shop.json'.

How do I redirect the shopBlock variable to the Django file?!  I am very lost

```
import shopblock from '../data/shop/shop.json';
import category from '../data/shop/category.json';

// Product details
function getProduct(id) {
    return shopblock.filter(product => { return product.id === parseInt(id) })[0];
}
// Count Category
```

Comment: I have managed to build a fetch request in the function getProduct(id).  The code is here `function getProduct(id){
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/products/")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
    return shopblock.filter(product => { return product.id === parseInt(id) })[0];
}`.  It returns the data and logs the data to the console but I am unable to then use and filter the data using `return data.filter(product => { return product.id === parseInt(id) })[0];`